# Why doesn't work command "git help" with other commands?

Tags: git, github, cmd, git-bash

I'm going through a git tutorial and I want to call the command "git help log", but after the call shows an error:

[Console with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Kgy.jpg)

Although the "git help" command works:

[Confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26hXx.jpg)

Comment: `git help log` is correct command. There is some problem with installation probably. Does git log work?

Comment: @vish4071 Yes,command git log works

Comment: Please post the output of your commands as text and not as images.

Comment: Which `git` is being run? What is the output of the command `where git`?

Comment: @lit command `git` shows all commands

Comment: @Problemon - I am not asking about the output of `git`. I am asking about the output of `where git`. My machine has ten (10) `git.exe` files on it. You might have some from installing Windows git, Visual Studio, github desktop, etc. The question is, which one is being run when you do not get the expected results?

Comment: @lit How can I find out?

Comment: What is the output of the command `where git`?

Comment: @lit `bash: where: command not found`

Comment: Reproduced with Windows 10 and fresh install of `PortableGit-2.34.0-64-bit.7z.exe` When you run "git help log", it opens a folder (i.e., spawns Explorer) to the drive git was installed on. There's not supposed to be any configuration needed for portable git, but maybe this is an undocumented limitation/glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the help page of `git log` you should use `git log -h`.

In general `-h` shows the help section of most commands in git

Comment: Thanks everything seems to work, but why the command "help" does not work as in the tutorial?

Comment: @Problemon which tutorial are you working with? Should probably be mentioned in the question